# How to precompile scss to a single css file in webpack?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Using React with webpack.
Ran through some articles, but most of them suggest calling individual scss file for each component. But I would like to precompile all css into single file for entire application like we do using grunt/gulp.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [webpack-text-extract-pluggin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) that is in charge of compiling all css files and bundling them in an `index.css` file.

Also note that you'll need to install [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) too in order to compile the scss.

In the webpack config:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
config = {
    ..., 
    plugins: [
        ...,
        new ExtractTextPlugin('index.css')
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style','css')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css">
```

In any Javascript file that gets through webpack:

```
require("./styles/my-custom-file.scss");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

After requiring this in your webpack.config.js:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
```

You can rewrite your sass loader to this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
        {test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css', 'sass')}
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
]
```

For more options and usage check the link above.

Comment: Thanks @erik-Martijn